# Intellisense automatically disabling with "WITH Inline = OFF"?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019

In my SSMS (I'm using 18.10) project, I've been frustrated by the fact that Intellisense is not functioning in my files. I had conjectured that it was due to the size of the codebase, but in fact, I found somewhat far weirder.

In the following code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION X() RETURNS INT
WITH INLINE = OFF
AS
BEGIN
RETURN 1;
END;
```

If I remove WITH INLINE = OFF, Intellisense turns back on. What is going on?

Comment: For the record please include your version of SSMS (mine is 18.10 and does this).

Comment: (I'm away from my SSMS to check myself, but...) Does this happen on functions and procedures? The `WITH INLINE...` syntax is only documented on Functions, so I'm honestly surprised that it doesn't throw an error on `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft 18.10 as well

Comment: No this is not valid syntax, see fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8f19ec89b8c6e19dbe9831bce5a47561 and see full syntax https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax, and even if `CREATE PROC` supported `WITH INLINE` you would expect it to be before the `AS`

Comment: @Charlieface My bad, I transcribed my code incorrectly. See edits. I've found the same behavior with functions too, so I've used your example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is going on?

A bug in the product. It looks like anything of the format

`WITH foo = ON` or `WITH foo = OFF` causes an unhandled exception during parsing.

Specifically an exception in

`Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.dll!Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.SqlCodeDom.SqlFunctionDefinition.SqlFunctionDefinition(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.SqlCodeDom.SqlObjectIdentifier name, System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.SqlCodeDom.SqlParameterDeclaration> parameters, System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.SqlCodeDom.SqlModuleOption> options, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.SqlCodeDom.SqlModuleOptionMask validOptions)`

Due to it ending up with a null `SqlModuleOption` value in the options` collection

[image]

Probably not much that can be done about this except report it to the developers.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's a bug somewhere. Thanks for reporting it (on behalf of the SSMS Team).

I'll take a look and see if I can get a fix for it in a future version of SSMS.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. Another (potential) bug with Intellisense is that occasionally for my larger files, Intellisense will turn off if SSMS idles. The only way to turn it back on, I've found, is to disable/enable Intellisense and then clear the cache with CTRL-SHIFT-R

Comment: @RushabhMehta - all these "intellisense disables itself" problems are usually caused by an uncaught exception somewhere in the parser. Big scripts with partial code may trigger (unwanted) stack overflows or other problems.... It would be nice if you could share your code (maybe a smaller/sanitized version). The typical place to reach out for issues is UserVoice: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server. I believe it also supports sharing files in a "private" way.

Comment: I'll definitely submit a code sample there. Thanks!